# Triple-slash directive failing within specific @types files Typescript >= 2.4.1

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

**TypeScript Version:**  Succeeds in 2.3.2; 2.4.0; Fails in 2.4.1; 2.4.2; 2.5.0; 2.5.2

**Code**

```
/* 
 * From @types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts  
 * https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/60e2268280174d6facc0a63da293cd4d80b45e0d/types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts
 *
 * Expected to link to the local version of this file:
 * https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/60e2268280174d6facc0a63da293cd4d80b45e0d/types/webvr-api/index.d.ts
 *
 * Note that types for three and webvr-api are properly installed; 
 * the typing files are the same when in successful typescript versions 
 * (e.g. 2.4.0) and in failing versions (e.g. 2.4.1). The typings are 
 * installed from NPM and are @types/three@0.84.22 and @types/webvr-api@0.0.31
 */

/// <reference types="webvr-api" />
```

**Expected behavior:** This file is resolved: /myProject/node_modules/@types/webvr-api/

**Actual behavior:**

```
/* Compile time errors */

ERROR in /myProject/node_modules/@types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts
(22,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.

ERROR in /myProject/node_modules/@types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts
(1,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webvr-api'.
```

I assume this is a problem with Typescript rather than the typings themselves being incorrect or out of date; failing resolution due to an intended change in Typescript should only happen across major versions (since it would be a breaking change).

Thoughts? Am I missing something?